Error while installing Ubuntu 24.04
Every time I try to install Ubuntu 24.04 on a new SSD I get this error and the installation freezes.


Too small to read. Have you updated system firmware & SSD firmware to latest available. Does live installer work in live mode without any issues. What brand/model system and what video card chip. What version of Ubuntu?
